# Closest sphere on segment

Tags: shader, glsl, mathematics, hlsl, signed-distance-field

I am trying to get a segment closest point on a surface and display a circle (or sphere in this case) at that position.

I actually get the correct position but I can't get a uniform sphere based on the computed data.

[image]

Here's the associated code I use to find the intersection point and draw the sphere.

```
float3 a = from;
float3 b = to;
float3 c = worldPosition;

float3  ab = b - a;
float t = dot(c - a, ab) / dot(ab, ab);
float3 point = a + saturate(t) * ab;

return length(point - worldPosition) - radius;
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. You have a line segment and you are trying to use a fragment shader to display kind-of a clipped distance field on the mesh surface?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a line segment and I compute the surface intersection closest point using the cylinder fragment shader. Using this closest segment point I compute a sphere distance field. Everything is done in world space.

Comment: Should there be a black circle displayed also when there is no true intersection but only strong proximity?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, the main issue is the deformation of the computed length which should be uniform. I guess that there should be a black circle when there's no true intersection because it illustrates the distance but it should be uniform.

Comment: Got it, I will try to answer the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your *actual* result is correct in terms of what you can achieve in a single-pass with a fragment shader. It calculates the distance of the fragment's world position to the line segment. That distance is **different for each fragment** so the stretched black ellipsoid is the correct output.

A fragment shader has only local information about the current fragment being processed. You can't do more with that. Your *expected* result requires some global knowledge about the scene, since you are searching for the **minimum distance across the whole surface**.

Without any thoughts on optimization, the naive solution path should involve contextual computation of local minima of the fragment-to-linesegment distance. In order to get such context, you need to compute the distance field first and then access it to find the local minima in a separate pass.

1. Compute the raw distance field in the first pass (same as your example but no `radius` subtraction at the end.
2. Mark the pixels with local minima in the second pass (e.g. by setting the alpha channel to 1). This will be screen-space pass. The best is to have a `rgba` float texture at output with `rgb` being fragment's world position and `a` being 1 for local minima and `0` else.
3. Paint the black circles/spheres in a third pass (also screen-space).

Having the information about the local minimum of your distance function enables you to output the right shape for around the minima in the last pass. In pseudocode:

```glsl
vec4 worldPos = tex2D(distance_texture, frag.x, frag.y);
if (worldPos.a > 0.5) //is minimum
    return vec3(0,0,0);
else
{
    //Sample the screen-space neighborhood in larger and larger circles
    // until a fragment with distance.a == 1 is found
    // or until all fragments are more than radius away (in world coords).

    //Minimum world space distance of any sampled fragment.
    float minDist = 0.0;
    int iter = 1;
    //Search for a local minimum until all fragments are more than radius away,
    // since then even if a local minimum gets found it will no longer produce
    // the black shading.
    while (minDist < radius && minDist >= 0.0 && iter < Math.Max(screenWidth, screenHeight))
        minDist = sampleNeighborhood(iter++, worldPos);

    if (minDist < 0.0) //found a local minimum
        return vec3(0,0,0);
    else
        return vec3(1,1,1); //or any other computed shading

    //I am aware that the function call above checks central fragments several times.
    //That should be of course optimized in production code.
}

float sampleNeighborhood(int neigh, vec4 worldPos)
{
    float minDist = float.MaxValue;
    for(int x = Math.max(0, frag.x - neigh); x <= Math.Min(screenWidth, frag.x + neigh; ++x)
        for(int y = Math.max(0, frag.y - neigh); x <= Math.Min(screenHeight, frag.y + neigh; ++y)
        {
            float p = tex2D(distance_texture, x, y);
            float d = distance(p.xyz, worldPos.xyz);
            if (p.a > 0.5 && d <= radius)
                //Return negative distance to indicate a local minimum was found.
                return -1.0; 
            else
                minDist = Math.min(minDist, d);
        }
    return minDist;
}
```

Finding the local minima in the second pass is much easier, since you only need to sample the local 3x3 neighborhood.

I hope that helps you in reaching the desired rendering!

Comment: Notice, that the same question is also on the game development site: [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/183427/closest-sphere-on-segment). I wasn't sure how to handle this, so I found this [Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/duplicate-questions-on-other-se-sites) - Long story short: Maybe you could provide your answer there too by copying or linking it (Don't want to farm reputation that you earned ;) ).

Comment: Thank you :) Haha it automatically converted it to a comment stating that it is trivial :)